# Performing Queries using EF Database first through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm new to .NET development and I have a backend DB on SQL server which I have generated from Database with Entity Framework.

I now want to access the data using WCF - How does one query a database through a windows service or, in general, query a database first DB?

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you should look to abstract away your database logic behind your web services.  For example each WCF web service should provide CRUD (create read update delete) functions for a given entity (e.g. user).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have made an EF model with your db?

EF will have created a `Context` class for you (probably a `DbContext` depending on the version of EF used).

You can then instantiate an object of this class, and perform operations against it such as querying. It will contain the DbSet collections matching your tables/collections defined in your model.

So, for example, I have created a model which contains one table called 'Products' and I can perform queries against the db using the generated context like this:

```
var context = new MyGeneratedContextClass();
var results = context.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductId.Equals(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this allows you to very easily expose an Entity Framework model (or part thereof) as a REST/OData webservice.